# Compressing string with repeating chars

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, compression

I have string which contains only 'U', 'D', 'L', 'R' chars (directions in labyrinth).

The string may look something like this:

- RRRRRDRRDDDRRUUUUDDRRRRUULLU
- DDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDL
- LUUURRDRRDLUUURRDRRD

I want to compress this sequence of instructions.

For example.

1.
before compression: ULULUL
after compression:  3(UL)

2.
before compression: DDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDLDDL
after compression:  10(DDL)

3.
before compression: LLLLDLLLLDLLLLD
after compression:  3(4LD)

Does anyone know such algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Data compression is modelling (distinguishing probable from improbable) and coding (considered solved). Coding repeated sequences is connected to the names of A. Lempel and J. Ziv. Especially your #3 reminds me of the "compressed pointer macro(?method?)" - dimly remember reading about it in the context of OPM(/L), EPM, … in "Combinatorial Algorithms on Words (Apostolico, A.; Galil, Z. (Eds.))" (978-3-642-82456-2) - it's been a decade, or three.

Answer (score 2):

No, do not use run-length encoding, the result will be awful.

Instead, do bit-packing: Encode each of your four directions in 2 bits, and then pack four 2-bit pairs into a byte.

So: `U` = 00b (0d), `D` = 01b (1d), `L` = 10b (2d), `R` = 11b (3d).

(Note: 'b' suffix means binary, 'd' suffix means decimal.)

Therefore, `LLLL` = `10101010b` which is only 1 byte long.

**EDIT**

From a comment by the OP it turns out that the result of the compression needs to be a string consisting of only printable characters.  So, then, I would say that the algorithm that the OP needs is called [***Huffman Coding*** (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  I am not aware of any implementations that produce printable text, (as most would find that such a thing would completely defeat the purpose of compression,) but it is theoretically possible to implement the algorithm in such a way that the output would be printable characters.  Anyway, the OP is asking if anyone knows of such an algorithm, so, that's it.

Comment: The quality of the result entirely depends on the input. I.e. 1000L is much shorter than 1010...10.

Comment: @Mike Nakis,
 I need string result after compression, not binary.

Comment: Well, you should clearly state that in your question.  And since a sequence of bytes ***is*** a string, you should further specify that you want it to be a string consisting of only printable characters.

Comment: And, I amended my answer.

Comment: I want to do this for exercise. Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Huffman coding does not help in finding blocks of repeated characters and what substring is being repeated; it just assigns a "best" number to represent characters in a string which is different.

Comment: @Paddy3118 There is nothing about Huffman coding which mandates that its input domain has to consist of characters. Instead of "characters" think "input values". So, the OP can consider fixed-length groups of consecutive instructions as input values, so 4-instruction-long groups would give him an input domain of 16 different values which he can then huffman-code. He can even use characters as an intermediate step. For example, 5-instruction-long groups would give him an input domain of 32 different values, which he can then map to 26 letters + 6 digits = 32 characters.

Comment: @MikeNakis; I think you'd best expand on that algorithm as it seems to be a significant extension of Huffman coding.

Comment: If you read the wikipedia article that I linked to about Huffman Coding you will see that it speaks of ***source symbols*** such as *characters*. A source symbol can be anything you like, as long as you have a finite number of them, and Huffman will yield savings if the frequency distribution of symbols is sufficiently skewed.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I guess you could use the regexp solution here: http://paddy3118.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/find-repeated-blocks-of-characters-in.html to find what you call source symbols, and which I call chars in the regexp and Python code, but the OP just wants the chars and repeat count not a further Huffman coding of it.

Answer (score 1):

I created and blogged a solution that uses the Python regular expression engine to extract the blocks of repeated characters [here](http://paddy3118.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/find-repeated-blocks-of-characters-in.html).

It doesn't give the shortest answer in all cases but comes close.

The idea is to step through the non-overlapping matches to this regular expression:

`(?P<repeat>(?P<chars>.+?)(?:(?P=chars))+)`

Comment: unfortunately i can't use regular expressions i should write it with native C++ code.

Comment: @user3216905: C++ has regexp capability: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is classical [run-length-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) (a bit more involved than the simple approach which would just take repetitions of an individual character).

Comment: Unfortunately run-length encoding *is* that simple approach described. The devil is in finding/choosing which substrings are repeated more than once.